# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Multivariate Normal Distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, mle

I am trying to fit the parameters of a multivariate normal distribution using MLE.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mnorm

def estimation(obs,fun,init,method='Nelder-Mead'):
    mle = lambda param: -np.sum(fun(*[obs,param])) ## negate since we will minimize
    result = minimize(mle,init,method=method)
    return result.x
```

Fitting univariate normal distribution is fine:

```
obs = np.random.normal(1,4,50000)
ini = [0,1]
print(estimation(obs,lambda ob,p:norm.logpdf(ob,p[0],p[1]),ini))
```

But ran into some issues for multivariate (error assigning array to variable):

```
obs_m = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0],[[1,0],[0,100]],50000)
ini_m = [[0,0],[[1,0],[0,100]]]
print(estimation(obs_m,lambda ob,p:mnorm.logpdf(ob,p[0],p[1],ini_m))
```

It seems the optimization algorithm doesn't work for arbitrary arrays/matrices. I have to unpack the mean array and covariance matrix into a flat array to feed to minimize.

```
ini_m = [0,0,1,0,0,100]
print(estimation(obs_m,lambda ob,p:mnorm.logpdf(ob,[p[0],p[1]],[[p[2],p[3]],[p[4],p[5]]]),ini_m))
```

Obviously this will quickly go out of hand when the dimension increases or for some more complicated distribution without closed form solution. What is the best to do here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `optimize.minimize` *did* allow you to pass in a guess for `mean` and `cov` without modification - in whatever shapes you wanted - and it would pass in `mean` and `cov` arrays of the same shape to your negative log-likelihood function. Some elements of `cov` would be redundant, since it must be symmetric, and you would somehow need to add constraints to keep `cov` positive definite.

The solution below requires writing distribution-specific functions for conversion between a 1-D array of decision variables and distribution-specific parameters, but it scales to an arbitrary number of dimensions, and for `multivariate_normal`, it solves the problem of redundant decision variables and ensuring positive-definiteness.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize
rng = np.random.default_rng(747458538356)

def mle(obs, dist, params0, method='slsqp'):
    # Distribution-independent MLE function
    dim = obs.shape[-1]

    def nllf(x):
        params = x2params(x, dim)
        logpdf = dist.logpdf(obs, *params)
        return -np.sum(logpdf)

    x0 = params2x(params0)
    res = optimize.minimize(nllf, x0, method=method)
    return x2params(res.x, dim)


dist = stats.multivariate_normal

def x2params(x, dim):
    # multivariate_normal-specific function to convert decision variable
    # array to distribution parameters
    mean = x[:dim]

    # Decision variables are elements of Cholesky decomposition
    # to ensure positive definite covariance matrix
    L = np.zeros((dim, dim))
    indices = np.tril_indices(dim)
    L[indices] = x[dim:]
    cov = L @ L.T

    return mean, cov

def params2x(params):
    # multivariate_normal-specific function to convert distribution parameters
    # to decision variable array
    mean, cov = params
    dim = len(mean)
    indices = np.tril_indices(dim)
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
    return np.concatenate((np.ravel(mean), L[indices]))


# generate observations
size = 500  # number of observations
mean = [0, 0]
cov = np.array([[5, 2], [2, 10]])
params0 = (mean, cov)
obs = dist.rvs(mean, cov, size=size, random_state=rng)

# compare our function against reference
res = mle(obs, dist, params0)
ref = stats.multivariate_normal.fit(obs)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res[0], ref[0], rtol=1e-3)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res[1], ref[1], rtol=1e-3)

mean, cov = res

print(mean)
# [0.09533408 0.04011049]

print(cov)
# [[ 4.91358864  2.25704525]
#  [ 2.25704525 10.59167997]]
```